# (physicalsocketserver.cc:898): pipe failed while using libjingle_peerconnection library

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, live-streaming, libjingle

I am building a video streaming application using a libjingle_peerconnection library. But during conference application is crashed and I got the exception

```
10-16 10:45:10.600 21399-22442/com.shashank.demo E/libjingle: (physicalsocketserver.cc:898): pipe failed
10-16 10:45:10.602 21399-22442/com.shashank.demo E/rtc: #
# Fatal error in ../../webrtc/rtc_base/physicalsocketserver.cc, line 1582
# last system error: 9
# Check failed: err == 0 (-1 vs. 0)
# 
#
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.